# Activate WiFi on runlevel 3 startup

Tags: rhel, wifi, scientific-linux

I am running SL6. During GNOME session, the wifi is connected as soon as I login, however the same does not happen until I login.

The situation further worsens in runlevel 3 where the wifi is not connected even after login. I have tried many solutions related to *wpa_suppliant* over the internet but none seem to help. It seems like it is an [open bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=154348) in Fedora (which, I believe, is near-upstream for RHEL family).

Because I use the box in a headless manner and use it as NAT for other devices connected to it through ethernet, I would want it to be connected once it boots without logging in. Is there a solution?

Comment: are you using network-manager?

Comment: Yes, its part of Gnome and I am using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using network-manager make sure that the connection is `Available to all users` and that network-manager is executed - see http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-NetworkManager.html for more details.

If you don't want to use network-manager (the bug you referred to is only valid for interfaces files) have a look at http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/WpaSupplicant which should explain the necessary steps do setup a wireless connection with wpa an interfaces files.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution helped a lot and my problem, it seems, is solved.

Comment: [The asker writes:](http://unix.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2206) “My problem was solved by the WpaSupplicant solution (the CentOS link provided above). However, the solution contained in the link has one step that requires editing ifcfg-wlan0 (or equivalent) file for your wireless. Such a file did not exists in network-scripts folder and therefore I skipped the step, yet everything works fine as expected.”

Answer (score 0):

If you are using network-manager, I suggest switching to wicd instead. In my experience, network-manager seems to be designed mainly for graphical desktops. On wicd, it's much easier to manage wifi networks without graphical tools.